# Auto reply to another email

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013

How can I configure the "exchange 2010" or "Outlook 2013" auto-reply to mail. But not to the sender’s mail, but to the mail indicated in the message body.

Comment: In case you don't have any luck with Outlook on it's own, you *might* be able to find something through Microsoft Flow?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook client and Exchange server indeed didn’t have a built-in option to realize this. But I was able to find some similar threads.  The VBA code and VSTO add-in could help get the email address in message body. If you are familiar with code, you can check this:

[Need Help with VBA Code Auto-Generate Email Reply Based on Subject and Send To Email Address in Body](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/39fb2638-e82d-49db-b21e-cc4aba7724f9/need-help-with-vba-code-autogenerate-email-reply-based-on-subject-and-send-to-email-address-in-body?forum=isvvba)

[Body search and auto reply email](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5a8322cd-9093-48b1-ae2b-a533104bf95f/body-search-and-auto-reply-email?forum=outlookdev)